# Change Tufte-Book page numbers to bottom

Tags: page-numbering

I'm using a Tufte book template - and can not figure out how to change the page numbers so they're bottom center (not top outside edge).

(the generic template I'm using https://www.overleaf.com/10222634shztyfpxyhvn#/37826845/ )

I can't find where it is even coded to be top outer edge :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Unless you know what you are doing, it is better not to try modifying templates because commands there are too complex for non-programmers. You still can customize headers, footers, and page numbering using `fancyhdr` package. Use `\fancyhead{}` in the preamble to clear the headers and then redefine them as you like. Then use `\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{ \thepage }` to move the page numbering to the bottom. Here, `LE, RO` mean Left-Even and Right-Odd, which means that for even pages the numbering will be to the left and for odd pages, the numbering will be to the right. It is an almost universal page numbering practice.

A full code for an example is shown below:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{tufte-book}

    \usepackage{fancyhdr}

        \pagestyle{fancy} % allows for more advanced header and footer formats

                % Customizations
                \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{} }  % customize chapter name here
                \renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chapter}
                \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1} } % customize section name here

                % Define headers
                \fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{
                                                % Header and footer lines
                                                \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5 pt}
                                                \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0 pt}

                                                % Headers
                                                \fancyhead{} % clear header field
                                                \fancyhead[RO]{ \textbf{ \chaptername\ \thechapter:\ \leftmark } } % customize chapter name header here
                                                \fancyhead[LE]{ \hspace{4mm} \thesection \textbf{ \rightmark }  } % customize section name header here

                                                % Foot
                                                \fancyfoot{} % clear foot fields
                                                \fancyfoot[LE, RO]{ \thepage } % here is where the page position is defined
                                        }


\begin{document}

\title{Development of a Generalized PV Model in MATLAB/Simulink Using Datasheet Values}



\author{Al-Motasem I. Aldaoudeyeh
    \thanks{Al-Motasem I. Aldaoudeyeh is with the Department of Electrical and Computer Engineering, North Dakota State University, Fargo, ND, 58102 USA e-mail: almotasem.aldaoudeye@ndsu.edu}
}


\maketitle



\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\pagestyle{mainmatter}
\chapter{Chapter Name}


\section{Introduction}
\label{section:introduction}

    This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.

    This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.

    This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.

    This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.


\section{Numerical Results and Discussion}
\label{sec:results}

    This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.

    This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.

    This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit.


\section{Conclusions}
\label{sec:conclusions}


    This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.


\end{document}
```